# Coverting into JSON Array

Tags: javascript

This is my text file:

```
2|BATH BENCH|19.00
20312100000|ORANGE BELL|1.42
04525514840|BOILER ONION|1.78
20422500000|AVOCADO|0.98
```

My job is the extract the barcode which is 2,20312100000, 04525514840, 2042250000 and convert into a json array which should look like: `[\"2\",\"20312100000\",\"04525514840\",\"20422500000\"]`

The code I have is this:

```
var FilePath = process.argv[2];
var allUpcs = [];

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const file = readline.createInterface({
input: fs.createReadStream(FilePath),
output: process.stdout,
terminal: false
});

file.on('line', (line) => {
allUpcs.push(line.split('|')[0]);
});

file.on('close', function() {
// console.log(allUpcs.map(Number));
// console.log(JSON.stringify(allUpcs));
console.log(JSON.stringify(allUpcs));
});
```

I am getting output as this:

```
[“2”,“20312100000",“04525514840”,“20422500000"]
```

I need to convert it into json array, can anyone please help thank you.

Comment: The quotes are required in JSON. But they are required to be escaped in things like databases. So you need to clarify your need.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  splitting hairs came from where ? original data file ?

Comment: JSON is a string & Arrays are Arrays - When confused OPs post questions about JSON but show an example output that is an Array, it is not helpful to continue to feed them terminology that makes little sense. That's all, no biggie.

Comment: I am trying to convert into JSON array not JSON String.

Comment: It is an array, not a string until you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(allUpcs));` I think the code you have is what you want, but some reason you are expecting to see \ in the console which chrome does not show.

Comment: @mss Guessing you did not understand what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to do JSON.stringify twice, you can get the format you want.

Hava a good day :)

```js
const data =["2","20312100000","04525514840","20422500000"];
console.log('object',data);
console.log('string',JSON.stringify(data));
console.log('string',JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it in its fully stringified form, use `console.dir` rather than `console.log`. What you have is definitely JSON because you called JSON.stringify and your code didn't throw an error, `console.log` in Node just cleans that up for you. `console.dir` will show you that it is, in fact, a JSON string, and not an array.

Also it's important to note that `console.dir` behaves differently in different environments. Since you're in Node, using `console.dir` will give you the result that it sounds like you're expecting. If you were doing this in the browser, the result will be different.